# Ionic 2 - watch failed: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been trying to get the Ionic `watch` to work, but I've been getting an error. 
I created a brand new app with the following command:

```
ionic start my-app --v2
```

This seems to work fine, then I try to serve the app

```
ionic serve -p $PORT
```

However, I get the following error

```
watch failed: A watch configured to watch the following paths failed to start. It likely that a file 
        referenced does not exist: /home/ubuntu/workspace/my-app/src/**/*.(ts|html|s(c|a)ss)
```

I can see that the `src` folder does exist in the path shown in the error. Is there a way I can resolve this error? I'm using the C9 IDE and installed Ionic with the following command

```
sudo npm install ionic cordova -g
```

Here is my package.json in case it is needed:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "my-app: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: What version of npm have you installed?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio version 4.4.1

Comment: I guess that the problem is when `ionic serve` command is invoked, it calls an NPM script. This npm scripts call the `@ionic/app-scripts` library to execute the build process. Can you provide me the version of that? You can find this on your App dependencies. Try with another version.

Comment: @JonathanBrizio @I believe it is 1.1.4. In node modules folder I went to Ionic > App scripts > and looked at the package.json:  "@ionic/app-scripts@1.1.4"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I resolved it by deleting `node_modules` directory and run `npm install`